# Visual Studio Freezing/TFS Window Might be off screen

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, window, hidden, freeze

I am using Visual Studio 2005 with Team Foundation Server.

When I right click a file under the source control and choose "compare" VS appears to freeze until I hit escape.  My guess is that the window that is supposed to be popping up is somewhere I can't get to.  I tried minimizing all the windows that I can and it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I had the same issue when changing the monitor setup. Having three monitors in a weird pattern (laptop screen is below one monitor) seems to exacerbate the problem. I often get windows appearing invisibly in the air "under" the wrong monitor when I switch which side the laptop is on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the keyboard shortcut to get to the window's main menu () then hit 'M' for move and hit an arrow key to attach the window to the mouse - then at the next move of the mouse it should jump to it.

Experiment with a window you can see first.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  I'm not sure what you meant by the parenthesis, but the command I found for accessing the window menu was Alt+Space.

Comment: this is a good general solution for any application. I had a problem with TFS properties window in 2008

Comment: If Move didn't work for you: using the Windows Snap shortcut keys may do (Windows key + left/right arrow key).

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem when trying to check in to TFS - no dialog and ESC escape key undid the freeze.

I had recently, before the problem, changed my Laptop + Monitor configuration as follows:

from Primary screen being the laptop and secondary screen being the monitor

to primary screen being the monitor and secondary being laptop.

I got rid of my secondary screen and tried again.  SUre enough the invisible dialog was no longer invisible.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, it was indeed a dialog (or three) with incorrect screen geometry. Single screen reset them, and all is well now.

Comment: This is also what worked: Disabling the primary (laptop) screen didn't help, but temporarily disabling the secondary screen did actually revealed the dialogs permanently (at least for now).

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable my Second Screen as well. Now the check-in screen where you can add a comment *IS* visible.